# Use Mongo 3.0.2 in Mule 3.6.0

Tags: mongodb, mule

I was using Mongo 2.4 in the project that I'm working, then we decide to update to Mongo 3.0.2 because the system was not in production.  After update every operation I try to do in Mongo I receive the message: "Couldn't connect with the given credentials". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error happen because the authentication changed from MONGODB-CR to SCRAM-SHA-1 in Mongo 3.0.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/
The solution I found is to update the java mongo driver to version 2.13, as of this version it's possible to use mongo 3.0 http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/